# Undefined columns selected error with ggdensity command

Tags: r, dplyr, ggpubr

Newbie here in R, I try to show the density plot with the ggdensity command. However, I get this error message: Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , x) : undefined columns selected`.
Does someone know how this can be solved? It seems to me like I am specifically defining a column.
I would be thankful for your opinion.

My code:

```
alcohol.and.smoking <- read.csv("/Users/itamarmichaeli/Desktop/alcohol.and.smoking.csv")

df

library(gplots)


CrossTable(df$Do.you.consume.alcohol, df$Do.you.smoke.cigarettes , chisq = TRUE , expected = TRUE)

alcohol <- c(2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,2,2,0,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,0,2,1,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,0,2,2,1,0,2,2)

smoking <- c(1,0,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)

install.packages("ggpubr")
library(ggpubr)
library(dplyr)

ggdensity(alcohol.and.smoking, x = alcohol,
                add = "mean", rug = TRUE, color = “alcohol”, fill = “alcohol”, palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"))
```

dput() output:
structure(list(Students = 1:50, Do.you.consume.alcohol = c("Regularly",
"Regularly", "Regularly", "Regularly", "Regularly", "Rarely",
"Rarely", "Rarely", "Rarely", "Rarely", "Regularly", "Never",
"Regularly", "Regularly", "Regularly", "Regularly", "Regularly",
"Regularly", "Regularly", "Regularly", "Never", "Regularly",
"Regularly", "Never", "Regularly", "Rarely", "Regularly", "Regularly",
"Rarely", "Rarely", "Regularly", "Never", "Regularly", "Rarely",
"Regularly", "Rarely", "Rarely", "Rarely", "Regularly", "Regularly",
"Rarely", "Regularly", "Rarely", "Never", "Regularly", "Regularly",
"Rarely", "Never", "Regularly", "Regularly"), Do.you.smoke.cigarettes = c("Rarely",
"Never", "Regularly", "Never", "Never", "Never", "Never", "Rarely",
"Never", "Never", "Never", "Never", "Regularly", "Never", "Rarely",
"Regularly", "Never", "Never", "Never", "Never", "Never", "Rarely",
"Never", "Never", "Never", "Never", "Regularly", "Never", "Never",
"Never", "Never", "Never", "Never", "Never", "Never", "Never",
"Never", "Never", "Never", "Never", "Never", "Never", "Never",
"Never", "Never", "Rarely", "Never", "Never", "Never", "Never"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -50L))

Comment: Welcome to SO. For us to be of more help, we need to be able to reproduce the error you are receiving. Can you call the `dput()` function on your dataframe and edit the post to contain the output that R gives you so that we have the data?

Comment: do i just type dput(name of my dataframe)? or something different?

Comment: yup, just paste the output of `dput()` with the same of your dataframe inside the brackets

Comment: sorry for the stupid questions.. what do i do now once i made the command?

Comment: or should i just paste the output here?

Comment: You can edit your post and paste the output of the code at the bottom

Comment: `ggplot(alcohol.and.smoking) + 
ggdensity(aes(x = alcohol, add = "mean", rug = TRUE, color = “alcohol”, fill = “alcohol”, palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800")))`?

Comment: @sjp like this?

Comment: @Eyayaw this gives me the following error message:
Error: unexpected input in "ggplot(alcohol.and.smoking) +  ggdensity(aes(x = alcohol, add = "mean", rug = TRUE, color = “"

Comment: @jimhalpert I have the data now, but it doesn't really make sense to be plotting a density of this now that I see the data.

Comment: @sjp do you have an idea of how i can visualize the result differently?

Comment: I think one of the easiest ways would be to just plot the table `table(alcohol.and.smoking$Do.you.smoke.cigarettes, alcohol.and.smoking$Do.you.consume.alcohol)`, this shows the relationship in a compact way that is easy to read

Comment: @sjp thanks that works! and is it possible to show in a boxplot or histogram? or is the data not fitting?

Comment: The problem is that this data is categorical, and boxplots and histograms typically have some sort of continuous measure. You could do a barplot of the counts for each category, but a table gives the same information and takes up less space

Comment: @sjp ok i see, thanks! and say i turn both variables to numerical factors? e.g.  2 numerical vectors alcohol() and smoking() with the numbers 0-3 (regular, rarely, and never) or wouldn't it change the situation as it still would not be a continuous measure?

Comment: It doesn't really change the situation. You should look into other options for visualizing categorical data if you don't want to use a table

Comment: What are you exactly trying to accomplish? Other than that,  for plotting `ggplot2` works nicely with data.frames so put the `df` as well as `alchol` and `smoking` in one data.frame.

Comment: @Eyayaw not something particular, i'm trying to familiarize myself with R. i have this dataset and wanted to see if i can run some tests and then visualize the data in nice way. regarding the plots, how do i put them in 1 data frame?